# .NET IComparer sort error

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, compare, icomparer

I have run into a very weird issue recently.  I deployed a new version of a program and am receiving this error when the IComparer.Compare() method gets called internally:

```
Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare0 method returns inconsistent
results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value     repeatedly
compared to another value yields different results. x:",x's type: 'String',
IComparer.".
```

The odd thing is that I cannot reproduce this issue on my computer.  It doesn't happen for me in Visual Studio 2013 (debug or release versions) and it doesn't happen when I install the application either.  To make things weirder, it doesn't even happen on every computer in production, only about 30% of them.

My application targets .NET Framework 4 and the platform target is x86.

There is only one instance of an IComparer object in my code, here it is:

```
public int Compare(string stringOne, string stringTwo)
{
    if (stringOne == stringTwo) { return 0; }
    else if (stringOne == null) { return stringTwo == null ? 0 : -1; }
    else if (stringTwo == null) { return stringOne == null ? 0 : 1; }

    else if (stringOne.StartsWith("_") && !stringTwo.StartsWith("_"))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (!stringOne.StartsWith("_") && stringTwo.StartsWith("_"))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((stringOne.StartsWith("l") || stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
            (!stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || !stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ((!stringOne.StartsWith("l") || !stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
              (stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (stringTwo == null) { return 1; }
        else { return stringOne.CompareTo(stringTwo) == 1 ? -1 : 1; }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else had this issue and found a solution to it?  Does my comparer look it covers all cases?  I am totally lost about this issue and have no idea what to try next.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you put tracing in to see what the values are? that fail?

Comment: likely dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407412/where-is-the-inconsistency-in-this-icomparer-that-is-causing-a-null-reference

Comment: This doesn't directly help your question, but have a look at [`String.StartsWith(String, StringComparison)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you don't need to check for, say, both `l` and `L`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
else if ((stringOne.StartsWith("l") || stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
            (!stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || !stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if ((!stringOne.StartsWith("l") || !stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
              (stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

should be

```
else if ((stringOne.StartsWith("l") || stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
            !(stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (!(stringOne.StartsWith("l") || stringOne.StartsWith("L")) &&
              (stringTwo.StartsWith("l") || stringTwo.StartsWith("L")))
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

As a side note, the way you wrote this comparer function is highly ineffecient.

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up figuring it out on my own and it just so happens that this is exactly how I fixed it.